# I have to return filtered object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, filtering

I have array, which i get from checkbox checking.
And I have array of objects with categrories.
I want to get an array filteredPeople that contains only objects with categories that contains at least one of from selectedClicents

```
  let selectClients = ['Web', 'Design'];

  let people = [
    { category: ['Web', 'Design'] },
    { category: ['Web'] },
    { category: ['PWA', 'Design'] },
    { category: ['Ecommerce'] },
  ];
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7364150/4962985

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.some` and `Set.prototype.has` along with `filter` to get the filtered list from `people` array

I've used a ES6 `Set` for O(1) lookup:

```js
const selectClients = ['Web', 'Design'];

const keys = new Set(selectClients);

const people = [
    { category: ['Web', 'Design'] },
    { category: ['Web'] },
    { category: ['PWA', 'Design'] },
    { category: ['Ecommerce'] },
];

const res = people.filter(({category}) => category.some(cat => keys.has(cat)));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
let selectClients = ['Web', 'Design'];

let people = [
  { category: ['Web', 'Design'] },
  { category: ['Web'] },
  { category: ['PWA', 'Design'] },
  { category: ['Ecommerce'] },
];

let final = people.filter(({category})=> selectClients.some(v=>category.includes(v)))

console.log(final)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what i needed. I'm graphic designer starting as a developer and i'm just starting with javascript. Do you recommend some books or courses to learn javascript ?

Comment: @JaPod [`MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) is great source to learn about js, all the best with your learning mate :) also you should mark [`Amardeep's answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57680252/9624435) as correct answer, cause that is better than mine

Comment: @JaPod you can visit the SO [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) page of JavaScript, that page has a lot of resources.